# Show that the area vectors for a general tetrahedron sum to zero

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

Using vector addition and multiplication, it is possible to show that the sum of the area vectors for a general closed tetrahedron in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (3-space) is zero.

Hint: start by writing down three vectors: $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$, and $\vec{c}$ and derive relationships for the other sides in terms of $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$, and $\vec{c}$.

Comment: The hint is a good one. If $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$, $\vec{c}$ emanate from one vertex of the tetrahedron, then the vectors determining the remaining three edges are simply $\vec{a}-\vec{b}$ and $\vec{b}-\vec{c}$ and $\vec{c}-\vec{a}$ (although you only need two of them). How do you compute the area vector for a triangle determined by vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$?

Answer (score 5):

So for a general tetrahedron, we can derive that three of the sides are described by the vectors: $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$.

We can then write the area vector – using the outward pointing convention – for the first side as: $$\vec{A}_{ab} = \frac{1}{2}\vec{a}\times\vec{b}$$

Similarly, two of the remaining three area vectors can be written: $$\vec{A}_{bc} = \frac{1}{2}\vec{b}\times\vec{c}$$
$$\vec{A}_{ca} = \frac{1}{2}\vec{c} \times \vec{a}$$

The final area can be found using the fact that the vectors that define the sides define a closed figure and thus must sum to zero as suggested in the first hint by Blue:  $$\vec{A}_{(c-a)(b-a)}=\frac{1}{2}(\vec{c}-\vec{a})\times(\vec{b}-\vec{a})$$

Summing all of these we find that: $$ \frac{1}{2}\vec{a}\times\vec{b} + \frac{1}{2}\vec{b}\times\vec{c}+\frac{1}{2}\vec{c} \times \vec{a}+\frac{1}{2}(\vec{c}-\vec{a})\times(\vec{b}-\vec{a}) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{a}\times\vec{b} + \vec{b}\times\vec{c}+\vec{c} \times \vec{a}+(\vec{c}-\vec{a})\times(\vec{b}-\vec{a})\right) = \vec{0}$$

by applying the properties of distribution, simplifying the cross products and canceling.

Comment: This is good, although I was picturing $\vec a$, $\vec b$, and $\vec c$ as forming a right-handed system, and you apparently pictured the opposite. Sometimes an actual picture is a good thing. :)

Comment: Rather than leave the argument to off-the-page computation, go ahead and do the distribution:
$$\begin{align}(\vec{c}-\vec{a})\times(\vec{b}-\vec{a})&=\vec{c}\times\vec{b}- \vec{c} \times\vec{a}-\vec{a}\times\vec{b}+\vec{a}\times\vec{a}\\ &=-\vec{b}\times\vec{c}-\vec{c}\times\vec{a}-\vec{a}\times\vec{b} \qquad (+ 0)\end{align}$$ 
This clearly cancels the sum of the other area vectors.

Comment: This works for a tetrahedron. (+1) Extending this argument to a general polyhedron may be a bit of work.

Comment: Thanks Blue! I appreciate your working through the vector multiplication specifically. I am new to the site and also appreciate your taking the time to give me the helpful pointer!

Comment: robjohn, As George Joos points out in his book Theoretical Physics, any polyhedron can be made up of enough tetrahedrons of a small enough size.... I do admit I am trusting him and not exactly a proof, but an interesting insight.

Answer (score 3):

If $\vec{n}$ is outward unit normal to a face $F$ in then the (signed) area of the projection of $F$ onto a plane with unit normal $\vec{p}$ is $\vec{n}\cdot\vec{p}$ times the area of $F$. For a closed polyhedron, the projection of the faces pointing in one direction exactly match the projection of the faces pointing in the opposite direction.

Consider any polygonal prism with axis parallel to $\vec{p}$ whose intersection with a polyhedron are the red and green faces.

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

The area of the green face times $\vec{p}\cdot\vec{n}_g$ is the cross-sectional area of the prism. The area of the red face times $\vec{p}\cdot\vec{n}_r$ is the negative of the cross-sectional area of the prism. Their sum is $0$ and so is the sum over all prisms parallel to $\vec{p}$.

Since this is true for any $\vec{p}$, the sum of the area vectors for a general closed polyhedron is $0$.

Comment: I really like your hint robjohn, and I can see how we could use it directly to show that a tetrahedron with faces parallel to the three orthogonal planes (xy-, yz-, zx-) must have area vectors that sum to zero. Can you help me to find a proof for a general tetrahedron next using this insight? Do we need to slice up the general tetrahedron into smaller tetrahedra with these planes? Or maybe you were thinking of defining a new (non-orthogonal) coordinate system (s,t,u), using three sides of the tetrahedron as the (st-, tu-, us-) planes?

Comment: @HarveyRyanJohnson: I have expanded my answer from a hint.

Comment: Robjohn - I really like this approach! I think it works as long as the surface is orientable; however, for things like the Klein bottle it seems to break down (when the surface normal is not necessarily pointing outward). Can you think of a way to generalize this so that it works for orientable and non-orientable surfaces? Check out the general version over here if interested: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402594/show-that-the-area-vectors-for-a-general-n-sided-closed-shape-sum-to-zero

Comment: You'd have a hard time defining the signed area vectors on a non-orientable surface. On the Klein bottle, for instance, there is no global normal vector field to the surface.

Comment: As for the orientability of the surface, it follows from Alexander duality that a closed surface in R3 is orientable.  See e.g. Allen Hatcher's book. For instance, the Klein bottle is embedded only in R4.

Comment: @TheonAlexander: however, it can be immersed, and I think that is what Harvey was inquiring about. Indeed, if a surface has a distinct inside and outside, it must be orientable.

Comment: @robjohn You said that "For a closed polyhedron, the projection of the faces pointing in one direction exactly match the projection of the faces pointing in the opposite direction." Is there a formal proof of that? It's something I've been looking for for a while now.

Comment: @urquiza: that is what the rest of my answer is trying to show.

Answer (score 0):

*Idea based on Stokes' Theorem*

Sum of area vectors vanish for any solid (generalisable to solids bounded by non-planar surfaces):

Imagine a constant flux field. Then the surface integral of the normal vector dotted into the flux direction equates to the null accumulation inside the solid.

We can choose any orientation for the flux field, so the "average normal vector" is identically zero.

This is handwavy, but you can't beat it for succinctness.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you start with a triangulated surface forming a closed and orientable surface of any genus. Taking a typical triangle, as the surface is orientable, we can choose the coordinate vectors of the vertices a,b,c in a 'clockwise' direction. The area of triangle is then given by -(a^b+b^c+c^a)/6. Now take (without loss of generality) the adjacent triangle BAD also described in a clockwise direction. There will always be an adjacent triangle because the surfce is closed. The area is then -(b^a+a^d+d^b)/6. If these are summed the contribution from the adge AB cancels out as a^b+b^a=0. Likewise all the contributions from all the edges cancel down to zero. In conclusion the vector area of any triangulated closed and orientable surface is zero. Note, a Klein Bottle is not orientable.