# Show that the area vectors for a general $n$-sided closed shape sum to zero

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

It is possible to show that the sum of the area vectors for a general, closed, $n$-sided figure in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (3-space) is zero.

Hint: it may be easiest to consider orientable and non-orientable surfaces separately.

Comment: Long time ago I was told that this problem has a physical evidence. Fill the shape with a gas. Then the pressure vector of each side is proportional  to the area vector of this side,  and the total pressure vector is proportional to the sum of all area vectors. If the total pressure vector is non-zero,  then the shape should move in the direction of the vector. 
But it is well know that such a shape should not move. Therefore the sum of all area vectors is zero. :-)

Comment: How cool is that Alex! As a once engineer, I love the physical significance of your approach. Beautiful.

Comment: @HarveyRyanJohnson: how do you define area vectors on a non-orientable surface? Since it is not orientable, I see no way to define a continuous, single-valued normal on the surface. There is no "inside" or "outside" to use.

Comment: Excellent question. I was thinking that we might be able to use the non-orientability against itself. For the Klein bottle, the problem is that there are two area vectors – one on the "inside" and one on the "outside". By virtue of the fact that it is non-orientable, there exists a vector of the same magnitude but in opposite directions at every point on the surface. This means that the area vector will cancel with itself at every point as long as a complete trip is made. Does this satisfy us as a proof, or does it seem trivial? I feel a bit ambivalent about this. What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

A three-dimensional "body" $B\subset{\mathbb R}^3$, e.g., a ball, an octahedron, or a cylinder, has a boundary $\partial B$ which is an *oriented $2$-chain*, i.e., a union of smooth oriented pieces of surfaces, such that the "positive normal" ${\bf n}$ points to the outside at all points ${\bf p}\in\partial B$, where it is defined. For this situation one has Gauss' divergence theorem which says that
$$\int_{\partial B}{\bf v}\cdot{\bf n}\ {\rm d}\omega=\int_B{\rm div}({\bf v})\ {\rm d}{\bf x}$$
for all $C^1$ vector fields ${\bf v}$ on $B$. When ${\bf v}$ is a *constant* vector field then ${\rm div}({\bf v})\equiv0$, and we can write
$${\bf v}\cdot\int_{\partial B}{\bf n}\ {\rm d}\omega=\int_{\partial B}{\bf v}\cdot{\bf n}\ {\rm d}\omega=\int_B{\rm div}({\bf v})\ {\rm d}{\bf x}=0\ .$$
Since this is true for arbitrary ${\bf v}\in{\mathbb R}^3$ it follows that
$$\int_{\partial B}{\bf n}\ {\rm d}\omega=0\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

The dot product between an area vector and an arbitrary unit length direction vector $n$ is proportional to the area you obtain by projecting the area onto a plane orthogonal to $n$. So now consider your whole closed shape projected onto that plane. For every point in the plane, you can examine the ray originating from that point an in direction $n$. That ray must intersect the faces of the shape an equal number of times, half of them coming into the shape and half going out of it. So these whill exactly cancel, and the net effect is that there is *no* contribution of these areas to the point from which your ray originated. Since the same argument holds for all points (with some care for those intersecting edges, vertices and so on), you can tell that there will be *no* net contribution to *any* point of the projection. So the sum of the projected area vectors has to be zero. Since this is trie for *every* possible choice of $n$, you can tell that the sum of area vectors has to be zero, since the sum of dot products equals the dot product with the sum, and the only vector which has zero dot product with *every* unit-length vector is the zero vector.